How Do You Automatically Select The Entire Value Of A Text Field When You Select It In Android?
How do you select the entire value of a text field when you select it in Android?
The most common example I can think of this feature being used in is in a timer app. The timer is initially set to zero, which is usually formatted to 00. When you select the text field that holds the value of the timer, the entire value or 00 is selected. When you press a keyboard key the entire value is replaced by your inputs. There is no need to manually select and use backspace.
I don't know how to implement this feature.
Here is the code for the sample app I developed that tries to implement that feature.
// This variable holds the value of the text field. It is initially set to "initial text".
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("initial text") }

// This variable holds the state of the enabled parameter for the text field.
var isTextFieldEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

/* This is the conditional that selects the full text value when the button is enabled. 
   That's what it is supposed to do but it's not working */
if (isTextFieldEnabled) {
    TextRange(0, text.length)
}

// This is the layout of the application. The content is centered horizontally and vertically.
Column(
   Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
   horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
   verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {

   // This is the text field that I wish to select the total value of.              
   TextField(
      value = text,
      onValueChange = { text = it },
      enabled = isTextFieldEnabled,
      modifer = Modifier.clickable { isTextFieldEnabled = true }
)
}

Well that's all of the code. As you can see the textfield is clickable and when it is clicked it sets isTextFieldEnabled to true and that actives the conditional that is supposed to select the full text using TextRange. However this is not working. How do I modify the code to allow what I described in the question title.

This question is similar to: Select all text of TextField in Jetpack Compose. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I adjust the code, i think you might get the idea to continue it. even this not as you hope
var text by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("initial Text")) }
        //usually on disabled we cannot clicked the textfield
        //so i wrap it again on column
        //hopefully it clicked i don't test it
        Column(Modifier.clickable {
            text = text.copy(
                selection = TextRange(0, text.text.length)
            )
        }) {
            TextField(value = text,
                //enabled only when text selected is same as text length
                enabled = text.selection.length == text.text.length,
                onValueChange = { text = it }
            )
        }


It selects all of the text but only if it is disabled. If you also enable the text field when clicked, you'll still have to click it again to edit it but when you do that you lose the selection. It is a step in the right direction but it didn't quite answer the question. Thanks anyway.

No that didn't work. That time you couldn't even edit the text field at all. It disables when you click twice. I think the problem stems from their being a difference between having a text field disabled and enabled and having a text field selected and unselected. You have to press once to enable it and press again to select it. You lose the selected text status when you click twice.
